# Is there a way to make a discord bot customize an image?

Tags: javascript, image, discord, discord.js, bots

Basically what I want to do is create a discord bot (with discord.js) that is capable of customizing an image that I'll provide.

I want it to receive a command with some information, like some text lines and other .png images that the bot has to put on the image that everyone will use.

I already made the bot successfully; it responds to commands, and it's online 24/7 and such, but I haven't found yet a way to make this function possible.

I tried using the welcome images that other bots use, but I actually want the base image to be edited, so I couldn't use that method.

This is what I want to make with the base image (the black square with the yellow shapes is the base, everything else should be put by the bot using a command):

[image]

Comment: Check out [Canvas-NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the [Canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) library. You can refer to the [discordjs.guide's Canvas tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/canvas.html) to see a basic usage of it.